# Are Arrays really "sparsed" in JavaScript by default?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sparse-matrix

Are Arrays really "sparsed" in JavaScript by default?

How to delete single array element with no index shift?

What is the difference between:

```
var a = new Array(10);
var b = new Array(2);
```

Do these Arrays occupy different space in memory? Can I turn `Array(2)` into `Array(10)` and back?

**UPDATE 1**

The following code

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var a = new Array(10);
    var b = new Array(2);

    document.write('a[5] is ' + a[5] + '<br/>');
    document.write('a[15] is ' + a[15] + '<br/>');
    document.write('a.length is ' + a.length + '<br/>');
    document.write('b[5] is ' + b[5] + '<br/>');
    document.write('b[15] is ' + b[15] + '<br/>');
    document.write('b.length is ' + b.length + '<br/>');

    b[9]=12;
    delete b[9];

    document.write('After resize...<br/>');
    document.write('b[5] is ' + b[5] + '<br/>');
    document.write('b[15] is ' + b[15] + '<br/>');
    document.write('b.length is ' + b.length + '<br/>');

</script>
</body>
```

will return

```
a[5] is undefined
a[15] is undefined
a.length is 10
b[5] is undefined
b[15] is undefined
b.length is 2
After resize...
b[5] is undefined
b[15] is undefined
b.length is 10
```

So, I made `b` have the same properties as `a`. Can I do this without assigning fake value to `b[9]`? Can I do revers, i.e. having `a.length` being 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, arrays are sparse by default. Their properties aren't even defined. You can test it with this code:

   ```
   var arr = new Array(10);
   for(var x in arr) {
       alert(x); // Never alerts a number
   }
   ```
2. To delete a single element, use `delete`:

   ```
   delete arr[5]; // Deletes element 6.
   ```
3. Memory is likely irrelevant, and different engines will handle it differently. I don't think that can be answered accurately. As for changing dimensions, JavaScript arrays don't *have* fixed dimensions. This is perfectly legal:

   ```
   var arr = new Array(2);
   arr[5] = "Hello!";
   ```

You can read more about JavaScript in general on http://developer.mozilla.com/. Arrays are just objects with some extra special properties. It doesn't really have indexes so much as keys.

Comment: Yes I know this. But I wonder, since `new Array(10)` and `new Array(2)` are different in length property, although both are containing infinite number of 'undefined' members, then probably I have some else drawbacks?

Comment: I will infinitely add new elements to the end of an array and remove them from the beginning, having finite number of defined elements. Will javascript engine handle this?

Comment: @Dims: Yes. No limits. However, consider using `unshift()` to remove elements from the beginning and `push()` to add them to the end, otherwise `length` *may* grow too big to be measurable. This most likely won't be an issue, however.

Comment: Yes I need conserve position, so I need length to grow. Will this be ok?

Comment: For example I may need to have an array with defined elements from `a[1000000000]` till `a[1000000010]`. Is this ok?

Comment: @Dims: Are you sure you want/need an Array? Perhaps you'd just use an Object if you plan on having this "rolling" range. An Array will limit you to a 32 bit range.

Comment: And how Object can change this?

Comment: @amnotiam: No, it won't. Try it.

Comment: @Dims: An Object won't have a numeric range constraint. For example, `new Array(10000000100)` will give you a `RangeError`. If you do `a = new Array(); a[10000000100]`, it will work, but you're basically using the Array as an Object.

Comment: But what about speed? Will both cases work fast enough in ranges below 2^32? I don't want it to do hash search...

Comment: @minitech: If you want to use those indices with the magic of an Array, then yes, you're limited in range. Beyond the maximum range, you're just using it as an object.

Comment: ...example: `a = []; a[10000000100] = 'test'; a.pop(); // undefined`

Comment: @amnotiam: No, you're not; `length` works properly. And as for `pop()`, Dims has said he/she won't be using it anyway.

Comment: @minitech: `a = []; a[10000000100] = 'test'; a.length === 0; //true` Do you get a different result from this code? Where are you testing? (I'm using Chrome.)

Comment: @amnotiam: I do get a different result... I'm testing on Google Chrome Canary 16.x. It's 64-bit, I suppose.

Comment: @minitech: I have `Chrome 16.0.912.63 beta`, but I see there's an update awaiting. ES5 shows a 32bit range limitation. Do you suppose this is being removed for the next version?

Comment: @amnotiam: Sorry, my mistake, I have Chrome 18 :) *Small* error. Are you on a 64-bit OS?

Comment: @minitech: Yes, I'm on a 64-bit MacBook Pro. Must be a change between the version of V8 you're using and mine. I just tested in Node as well, and I get the same result. Sounds like you're on the cutting edge versions though.

Comment: @amnotiam: That explains it. I'm on Windows, which is obviously better in every way ;) Okay, seriously, though, I suppose you can't count on support so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @minitech: Heh, let the flamewar begin! ;) I'm actually leaning toward Linux more these days, but I digress... Gotta run. +1 for showing me the interesting 64-bit support (and for your answer of course).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the indices are just regular properties on an object.

If I do...

```
var array = new Array();
array[1000] = null;
```

...there's only one property added to the Array, though its `length` will be updated to `1001`.

---

To delete a single one without reindexing, use `delete`.

```
delete a[5];
```

---

The two arrays in your example are unique objects. Not sure what you mean by turning one into another.

Comment: @Dims: I see. Yeah, the `length` is basically the index of the top-most assigned index. It doesn't necessarily indicate the total number of defined properties of the Array. Like the first example in my question shows, adding one property at `1000` gives you a length of `1001`.

Comment: In my first example both `a` and `b` have no assigned index, neither topmost, nor bottommost. Just no assignments at all. Although arrays have different lengths.

Comment: @Dims: They do have a `length`. When you do `new Array(10)`, you're creating an Array with an initial length of `10`. You're right that there are no values at the indices. It's just that you can manually change the `.length` either using the constructor, or doing `my_array.length = 100`.